# App no está definida

Tags: angularjs

Estoy aprendiendo [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) versión 1.5.5, pero tengo algunos problemas con mi aplicación.

> Mi propósito en este ejemplo es usar al mismo tiempo las plantillas de [django](/questions/tagged/django) y de Angular.JS.

El archivo `.html` mínimo es este:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cmiApp">
  <head>
    <title>cmiApp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=""politica" ng-controller="PoliticController as pol">
      <div class="well well-lg">
        <p class="lead">
          {$ pol.label $}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/angular.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cmiApp/core.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

En el archivo `core.js` tengo esto, tomado del proyecto [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/app.js):

**core.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('cmiApp', [])
  .config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
  });

cmiApp.controller('PoliticController', function(){
  this.label = "Esta es mi política";
});
```

Pero tengo un error **de referencia** (*ReferenceError*) que dice que *"cmiApp no está definida"* y en la página veo `{$ pol.label $}`.

Estoy seguro que es una pregunta mu simple, pero no alcanzo a ver mi error, porque hasta donde alcanzo a entender estoy haciendo lo que indica el ejemplo [`$interpolateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en la definición del `controller`, siempre tienes que empezar con angular.module, prueba a cambiar la linea del controlador por

```
angular.module("cmiApp").controller('PoliticController', function(){
  this.label = "Esta es mi política";
});
```